# Unresolved overloaded function type in gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++14, function-templates

I am trying to pass a function template as an argument to another function as seen in the example below.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) foo(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename Fn, typename T>
decltype(auto) bar(Fn fn, T t)
{
    return fn(t);
}

int main()
{
    int arg = 0;

    std::cout << bar(foo<decltype(arg)>, arg) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

While this works in clang 9.0 and msvc v19.24 it fails with gcc 9.2

gcc output:

```
no matching function for call to 'bar(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int&)' std::cout << bar(foo<decltype(arg)>, arg) << std::endl;
```

Is this a bug in gcc? Also can i circumvent this somehow in gcc?

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/oCChAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supposed to be [a bug of gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64194), which has not been fixed even in [gcc 10.0.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ADDlRpFcPU3xOiN3).

It seems gcc fails to handling this case when specifying the return type with [placeholder type specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) like `auto` and `decltype(auto)`. If you specify the return type as `T` it would [work fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gWd2Uu0raDiazzZL).

Answer (score 2):

For gcc another workaround can be :

```
auto f = foo<decltype(arg)>;
std::cout << bar(f, arg) << std::endl;
```